# JQuery AppendGrid with JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

Have anyone tried integrating JQuery AppendGrid with Primefaces ?

I have this below AppendGrid JQuery, I want to pass the JSF managed bean parameters in the ctrlOptions. Does anyone have any idea, how can i do this ?

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
                        caption : 'CRR 115',
                        initRows : 1,
                        columns : [ {
                            name : 'Type of counterparty',
                            display : 'Type of counterparty *',
                            type : 'select',
                            ctrlOptions : {
                                0 : 'Please select',
                                1 : 'Regional Government',
                                2 : 'Local authority'

                            },
                            ctrlCss : {
                                width : '150px'
                            }
                        }, {
                            name : 'Region',
                            display : 'Region/District *',
                            type : 'textarea',
                            align: 'center',
                            ctrlAttr : {
                                maxlength : 100
                            },
                            ctrlCss : {
                                width : '150px'
                            }
                        },{
                            name : 'Region',
                            display : 'English *',
                            type : 'textarea',
                            align: 'center',
                            ctrlAttr : {
                                maxlength : 250
                            },
                            ctrlCss : {
                                width : '300px'
                            }
                        }, {
                            name : 'Name of counterparty',
                            display : 'Local Language *',
                            type : 'textarea',
                            ctrlAttr : {
                                maxlength : 250
                            },
                            ctrlCss : {
                                width : '300px'
                            }
                        }, {
                            name : 'Fiscal number of the counterparty',
                            display : 'Fiscal number of the counterparty',
                            type : 'text',
                            ctrlAttr : {
                                maxlength : 10
                            },
                            ctrlCss : {
                                width : '100px'
                            }
                        } ],
                        hideButtons : {
                            insert : true,
                            moveUp : true,
                            moveDown : true
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```